# Hibernate lazy loading doesn't work (@JoinColumnOrFormulas)

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I've this class

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "OD_STOCK")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "OD_STOCKID")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Stock")
public class Stock extends Entity  {

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "STOCKGROUPCODE", referencedColumnName = "GD_CODEID")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "GD_CODETYPE", value = "'STOCKGROUP'"))})
    private StockGroup stockGroup;

}
```

But when i load the Stock the stockGroup is always loaded... lazy loaded is not working.

I see in the SQL log this SELECT to load the stockGroup

```
   select
        stockgroup0_.GD_CODEID as GD_CODEI2_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.GD_CODETYPE as GD_CODET1_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERIN3_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUP4_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERI5_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERI6_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDA7_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDA8_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.VERSION as VERSION9_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.GD_CODE as GD_CODE10_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.ISACTIVE as ISACTIV11_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.PRINTORDER as PRINTOR12_52_0_,
        stockgroup0_.XMLGD_CODE as XMLGD_C13_52_0_ 
    from
        GD_CODE stockgroup0_ 
    where
        stockgroup0_.GD_CODEID=? 
        and stockgroup0_.GD_CODETYPE=? 
        and stockgroup0_.GD_CODETYPE='STOCKGROUP'
```

And worse when GD_CODEID is NULL in OD_STOCK the SELECT for load the object is done, when the SELECT is uneccessary as the GD_CODEID is NULL

The GD_CODEID is bind to NULL when GD_CODEID is NULL..

Why ? What can i do ?

Comment: How do you know that the value is not LazyLoaded? The moment you request for the stockGroup, it gets populated.

Comment: Because i see the SQL generated by hibernate and it's doing a select to load the stockGroup. When i select all the stocks, N more selects are done to load the stockGroup.